# error Failed to fetch diff for react-native@x.x.x Maybe it's not released yet? upgrading react-native from 0.59.4 to 0.60.6

Tags: react-native

I am trying to upgrade from react-native 0.59.4 to 0.60.6 but I am getting below messages:

> info Fetching diff between v0.59.4 and v0.60.6...
>
> error Failed to fetch diff for react-native@0.60.6. Maybe it's not released yet?
>
> info For available releases to diff see:
> https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge#version-changes

This is the command I use:

```
react-native upgrade 0.60.6
```

Some say this could be because of proxy configuration but I am not behind a proxy. Any help is appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows.

```
yarn add react-native @*version*
```

Pay attention to this.

If you're on a version <= 0.59.10 and want to go to e.g. 0.61, you need to upgrade to 0.60 first, then you can run the upgrader to get up to 0.61.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Apparently, `react-native upgrade` command is not working for all versions of react-native. I tried it for version 0.60.0 and it worked.

```
react-native upgrade 0.60.0
```

After this running `react-native upgrade` upgraded to the latest version.
P.S. There will be some files that won't be upgraded automatically. You will need to update them yourself.